# Datanucleus Query: accessing transient collection after close

Tags: collections, jdo, datanucleus, transient

I have a specific query method in all my managers that must return a **transient** collection, but i want to CLOSE the query immediately after executing it.

```
tx.begin();
Query query=pm.newQuery(...);
Collection col=(Collection)query.execute();
pm.makeTransientAll(col,true);
query.close();
tx.commit();
```

**The problem**: The collection CANNOT be accessed after the query is closed (DN knows the identity?) otherwise it throws a "Query has been closed" error!

**The solution**: Create a COPY of the original collection!

```
Collection col=new ArrayList((Collection)query.execute());
```

But i want to avoid that... Even if it's a local copy and it's not a deep clone, it still allocates the space needed for the entire array of elements (so, **at some point there is going to be 2x allocated memory**) and i would like to avoid that.

I'm i missing something? **Is there a way to avoid the creation of a clone**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found the reason of this behavior:

The query Object returned (collection) if an instance of:   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.**ForwardQueryResult**
that extends: **AbstractRDBMSQueryResult**
that extends: **AbstractQueryResult**
that extends: **AbstractList**

so, i get an object that is a LIST implementation, and the query result is bound to that implementation.

```
/** The Result Objects. */
protected List resultObjs = new ArrayList();

/**
 * Method to return the results as an array.
 * @return The array.
 */
public synchronized Object[] toArray()
{
    assertIsOpen();
    advanceToEndOfResultSet();

    return resultObjs.toArray();
}
```

So, i cannot avoid the creation of a NEW array...